# Python Parse CSV files contain JSON columns

Tags: python, json, csv, parsing, text

I have a csv file that contains JSON format text column.
Example:

```
employee = "{""eid"":""12345"",""firstName"":""alan"",""middleName"":"""",
""lastName"":""wang"",""gender"":""Female"",""dob"":""1991-1-11T00:00:00"",""maritalStatus"":""single"",
""partyType"":""Unknown"",""addresses"":[{""addressLine1"":""123 Main Street"",""addressLine2"":"""",""addressLine3"":"""",
""city"":""new york"",""region"":""NY"",""postalCode"":""10001"",""country"":""USA""}],""phoneNumbers"":[],""emailAddresses"":[],
""firstTimeLogin"":""2022-12-01T14:51:04"",""officeName"":""US-NY"",""companyCode"":""10001"",""workPattern"":""Unknown"",
""hoursWorkedPerWeek"":""40"",""hireDate"":""2011-11-11T00:00:00"",""employerName"":""Coca-Cola"",
""employerEid"":""1234"",""eligibilityId"":"""",""employeeId"":"""",""customerNumber"":""11111"",""loginId"":""@mailosaur.io"",""serviceAgreement"":""""}"
  
# parse x:
y = json.loads(employee)
  
# the result is a Python dictionary:
print(y)
```

I'm trying to parse is using json.loads but it's giving me format error:

```
Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

Please help!

edit:
Here is the full csv file

```
# read in the data
df = pd.read_csv('UA Consumer Object.csv')
df.head()
```

[image]

Comment: You have to parse the input as CSV first, then you can parse the individual JSON columns with a JSON parser.

Comment: Why is your data in such a horrible format?  What's with all the repeated `""` quotes everywhere?

Comment: As a python string literal, that's a concatenation of multiple strings, starting with `"{" + "eid" + ":" + "12345" + "," ...`,  So the actual string is `{eid:12345,`. You mention CSV but we don't see any CSV. Perhaps a sample of a few lines of the original CSV (with a smaller json example so we don't get eye strain) would help.

Comment: If I take that example and put it in a file then use `csv.reader` to unescape the quotes, I end up with a proper JSON document. So, I think its a question of how you read the csv more than the json part.

Comment: @JimGarrison Yes, I used pd.read_csv first and did df['json'] = df['json'].apply(json.loads). It's giving the same error

Comment: @tdelaney I used pd.read_csv to read the file, I added the csv above

Comment: What does `print(df['json'][0])` look like? And can you post the first 2 lines of the CSV as text so we can try it ourselves?

Comment: It seems like this data is being CSV encoded twice - that would be a problem with the .csv file itself. CSV can add `"` to a cell so that it can have embedded commas without those being mistaken for column separators. And then the quote itself is escaped by using two in a row, `""`. That's what we see in the dataframe column. But with its default paramters, pd.read_csv should have unescaped. So either you are using different parameters, or the .csv file is not right.

Comment: @tdelaney I just added it to the post

Comment: @tdelaney got it, I removed the double quote and changed everything to single and it worked. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

**First:** There is a syntax error that is tricking you.
You are not defining the ***employee*** string properly.

In python you can enclose strings with single ('example') or double quotes ("example").
Because your json contains double quotes you cannot use double quotes to enclose it.

**Second:** The json standard is having the same issue as python (double quotes wrapping double quotes). You would need to escape the double quotes if you intended for the strings inside the json to contain wrapped quotes.

I have handled the double quote issue by removing them.
Here is a corrected sample that runs in python

**PS:** I use the \ character to create a *multiline statement*.  It allows multiple lines to be interpreted as a single line.

```
import json

employee = '{""eid"":""12345"",""firstName"":""alan"",""middleName"":"""",\
""lastName"":""wang"",""gender"":""Female"",""dob"":""1991-1-11T00:00:00"",""maritalStatus"":""single"",\
""partyType"":""Unknown"",""addresses"":[{""addressLine1"":""123 Main Street"",""addressLine2"":"""",""addressLine3"":"""",\
""city"":""new york"",""region"":""NY"",""postalCode"":""10001"",""country"":""USA""}],""phoneNumbers"":[],""emailAddresses"":[],\
""firstTimeLogin"":""2022-12-01T14:51:04"",""officeName"":""US-NY"",""companyCode"":""10001"",""workPattern"":""Unknown"",\
""hoursWorkedPerWeek"":""40"",""hireDate"":""2011-11-11T00:00:00"",""employerName"":""Coca-Cola"",\
""employerEid"":""1234"",""eligibilityId"":"""",""employeeId"":"""",""customerNumber"":""11111"",""loginId"":""@mailosaur.io"",""serviceAgreement"":""""}'

employee = employee.replace('""', '"')
print(employee)

# parse x:
y = json.loads(employee)
  
# the result is a Python dictionary:
print(y)
```